# Infinite scroll download plugin vs. custom made

Tags: javascript, infinite-scroll

I am making a webapp which is mostly about infinite scrolling. Is it better to download a working infinite scroll plugin or should I make my own kind. I was thinking that in a web app it is better to use plugins which are constantly updated than making a custom made functions. I am new to web developing and my programmer has made a custom one. I just need to be sure it is ok or should we use a downloaded plugin?

Answer (score 0):

If it's a project that you are doing for fun or to learn something, then it's better you do a custom plugin. But if you are working for a client and have fixed timeline to implement the requirement, then you should go with an already stable plugin to begin with. You can make your plugin to suit your needs after you understand how things should work and the problems you will most likely to face. Infinite Scroll has lot to do with server interaction and takes a bit of time and  learning to build a highly stable plugin. So the choice is yours.

Some of the stable infinite scroll plugins

[JScroll](http://jscroll.com/)

[Infinte Scroll (no more support)](https://github.com/infinite-scroll/infinite-scroll)

Comment: its a serious game changing project on the market....no fun, nothing to learn and no clients :) thats why im so curious to know. which of those 2 options would u prefer in this case?

Comment: @Matush If you doing something game changing, then I would suggest you to go with a stable plugin as you can put your hard work on what really matters. Why waste your time in rebuilding something that already exists just for the fun of it? Good Luck :)

Answer (score 0):

I would personally prefer a custom made plugin so that we can have end to end control of the code and it's not that hard as it seems.

Below snippet can be used to detect if a user scrolled to the bottom of the page, there are three different ways to detect choose the one which suits your need. After detecting if the user is near-to-bottom / bottom to the page perform a action accordingly, like getting a HTTP response and binding items, etc.

```js
// Exactly bottom
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
        alert("bottom!");
    }
});

// Near bottom
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 100) {
        alert("near bottom!");
    }
});
// Get Scroll Percentage
window.addEventListener("scroll", function(e) {

    // What % down is it? 
    var scrollPercentage = (document.documentElement.scrollTop + document.body.scrollTop) / (document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight);

    console.log(scrollPercentage); // or for 100 scale - console.log(scrollPercentage * 100);

});
```